# How to get mouse hover events for shapes with a hole in a QGraphicsItem?

Tags: python, qt, mouseevent, pyside, shapes

I have a `QGraphicsPathItem` in Qt (using the PySide bindings in Python) where there is a big rectangle and a smaller rectangle inside. Because of the default filling rule (`Qt.OddEvenFill`) the inner rectangle is transparent. This effectively draws a shape with a hole.

Now I want to listen to mouse events like enter, leave, click, ... My simple approach of implementing `hoverEnterEvent`, .. of `QGraphicsItem` does not create mouse events when moving over the hole because the hole is still part of the item even if it is not filled.

I want to have a `QGraphicsItem` derivative that displays a custom shape whose outline is defined by a `QPainterPath` or one or several polygons and that can have holes and when the mouse enters a hole this is regarded as outside of the shape.

Example shape with a hole (when the mouse is in the inner rectangle it should be regarded as outside of the shape and mouse leave events should be fired):

[image: Shape with a hole]

However the solution should also work for arbitrary shapes with holes.

Example code in PySide/Python 3.3

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyPathItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('inside')

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print('outside')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
path.addRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
path.addRect(25, 25, 50, 50)

item = MyPathItem()
item.setPath(path)
item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue))

scene.addItem(item)

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.resize(200, 200)
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that method `shape` from `QGraphicsItem` by default [returns the bounding rectangle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#shape). Its returned path is used to determine if a position is inside or outside of a complex shape. However in case of a `QGraphicsPathItem` we already have a path and returning this instead of the bounding rectangle could solve the problem. And to my surprise it does.

Just add these two lines to the `QGraphicsPathItem` derivative from the question.

```
def shape(self):
    return self.path()
```

Comment: In the end it seems easy but it is also a bit counterintuitive if you don't know that `shape` returns by default always the bounding rectangle. That's why I leave the question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend event handler to check if a given position is the specific (inner) path. Different approach - draw using move/lineTo (maybe ambiguous). For example moveTo/lineTo:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyPathItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsPathItem.__init__(self)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        print('inside')

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        print('outside')

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()

path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
path.moveTo(0, 0)
path.lineTo(100, 0)
path.moveTo(0, 0)
path.lineTo(0, 100)
path.moveTo(100, 100)
path.lineTo(0, 100)
path.moveTo(100, 0)
path.lineTo(100, 100)

item = MyPathItem()
pen = QtGui.QPen()
pen.setWidth(25)
pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
item.setPen(pen)
item.setPath(path)

scene.addItem(item)

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
view.resize(200, 200)
view.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: For the first idea I don't know exactly how to do that. For the second I guess it would not work with more customary shapes because you replaced an area with a set of thick lines. What if the thickness is not always constant?

Comment: First idea is even more quirky, you have to remember hole's paths and handle moveEvent https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent